# I need a set which uncountable has one property.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am looking for a subset $A$ of a topological space $X$ such that $A$ is uncountable but when you remove one point then become a countable, (i.e. $A-\{x\}$ become countable).

I suspect that $\omega_1$ could serve us but I cannot show how ? and in what topology?

Comment: The corresponding thing with countable sets would be a countably infinite set that became finite with the removal of one element, which is also impossible.  In fact, removing any subset of smaller cardinality cannot reduce the cardinality of any infinite set.

Answer (score 4):

This is impossible. If $A$ is an uncountable set, and $x\in A$, then $A\setminus\{x\}$ is always uncountable. Topology has nothing to do with this.

Comment: what does it mean a smallest uncountable set which is $\omega_1$, it is not mean, when you remove something then it will not stay uncountable !

Comment: @Dayana: No, it doesn’t. It means that if $A$ is any uncountable set, then $|\omega_1|\le|A|$, i.e., there is an injection $f:\omega_1\to A$. There is no uncountable set that is strictly smaller in cardinality than $\omega_1$.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I understood.

Comment: More generally, for any set $A$ of  *infinite* cardinality, $A\setminus\{x\}$ has the same cardinality as $A$.

Comment: @Dayana: You’re welcome.